# Prove that $\exists x_0 \in D$ such that $f(x_0) = (0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Here's the question (from last quarter's final):

> Define $D$ to be the closed unit disk, that is $D = \{(x_1,x_2):x_1^2 + x_2^2 \leq 1\}$. Let $f:D \to \mathbb{R}^2$ be a $C^1$ mapping.  If $f'(x)$ is invertible for all $x \in D$ and
>   $$
> |f(x) - x| \leq \frac 13, \quad x \in D
> $$
>   prove that there exists a point $x_0 \in D$ such that $f(x_0) = (0,0)$.

**Thoughts so far:** clearly, the inverse function theorem applies, so that $f^{-1}$ can be defined in the neighborhood of any point.  Furthermore, the inequality applies so that
$$
|x - f^{-1}(x)| \leq \frac 13, \quad x \in f(D) 
$$
I'm not sure how any of this would allow me to show that $0 \in f(D)$, so I'm pretty much stuck for now.

Any input, be it a gentle nudge or full solution, would be very much appreciated.

**EDIT:** As copper.hat points out, the Brouwer fixed-point theorem makes quick work of this problem.  However, I am still looking for a solution "in the spirit of the question", hopefully one that uses the existence of an inverse in  the neighborhood of each point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $\phi(x) = x -f(x)$. Then $\|\phi(x)\| \le {1 \over 3} $ for all $x$ in the closed unit ball. Since the closed unit ball is compact and convex, the Brouwer fixed point theorem shows that $\phi$ has a fixed point in the unit disk. Hence $f(x) = 0$ at this fixed point.

**Note**: $\phi(x) = x$ iff $f(x) = 0$.

**Alternative proof**:

Let $\eta(x) = {1 \over 2 } \|f(x)\|^2$. Since $\eta$ is continuous, it has a minimum at some point $\hat{x} \in D$.

The hypotheses show that $\eta(x) \ge {2 \over 3} $ for $\|x\| = 1$, and $\eta(0) \le {1 \over 3}$, hence we have $\hat{x} \in D^\circ$, and so
${\partial \eta(\hat{x}) \over  \partial x} = 0$ at the minimum. Since
${\partial \eta(\hat{x}) \over  \partial x} = {\partial f(\hat{x}) \over  \partial x} f(\hat{x})$ and the derivative is  invertible, we have $f(\hat{x}) = 0$ as required.

Comment: We would have $f(x) = x$ at this point.  Is there any particular reason that this point should be $x = 0$?

Comment: You would have $\phi(x) = x$, which happens **iff** $f(x) = 0$.

Comment: Ah, I see.  So by this method, we only need $f(x)$ to be continuous.  Where did convexity factor in?

Comment: Brouwer... ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: I imagine there is a simpler proof for $\mathbb{R}^2$ using the existence of a local inverse, but it escapes me...

Comment: I had forgotten that Brouwer required convexity.  At any rate, thank you!  I am still looking for an analytic proof in the spirit of the question, so I will not be accepting your answer for now.

Comment: Picky! OK, let me see if I can produced something more analytic...

Comment: I added a proof that uses more hypotheses...

Comment: aha! Very good. I have no more excuses, then.

Comment: Just kidding :)