# If $D=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$. Show there is $p_0\in D$ such that $T(p_0)=(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let $D=\{(x,y):x^2+y^2\leq 1\}$, $T$ transformation of class $C'$ on an open containing $D$, $$T:\left\lbrace \begin{array}{rcl} u &=& f(x,y) \\ v&=&g(x,y)  \end{array}\right.  $$  whose Jacobian is never $0$ in $D$, and $|T(p)-p|\leq \frac{1}{3}$ for all $p\in D$. Show there is $p_0\in D$ such that $T(p_0)=(0,0)$

**Idea:** Seems like fixed point theorem can help, for example if  I define  $H(p)=T(p)-p$, then $H(p)=p$ iff $T(p)=0$, so it's enough to find such point for $H$, by hypothesis $|H(p)|\leq \frac{1}{3}$ . Usually the fixed theorem is stated as: if $f:D\to D$ is continuous then there is a fixed point, or also there is no retraction of class $C'$ from $D$ onto the unit circle (only the boundary of $D$). Here I know that the jacobian of $T$, $J(p)\neq 0$ for all $p\in D$ so there is a neighborhood of any $p\in D$ where $T$ is $1$-to-$1$, i.e., in where $T^{-1}$ exists. But at least for now I can't have a precise idea. Any hints are welcome.

For context, this is a problem #17 section 7.5 from Buck's Advance Calculus. In this section we have the results:

1. For $T:D\subset\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ of class $C'$, $D$ open, with $J(p)\neq 0$ for all $p\in D$ then $T$ is locally $1$-to-$1$ in $D$.
2. If $J(p_0)\neq 0$ only for a specific value, then $T$ is $1$-to-$1$ only in a small neighborhood of $p_0$, where $T^{-1}$ exists.
3. If conditions as in 1.,then $T(D)$ is an open set.

Comment: The bound on $|T_p - p|$ when viewed on $\mathbb{S}^1$ governs some topological properties of your map.  In complex analysis, this is often called "walking the dog."  Do you have Jordan Curve Theorem, Brouwer Fixed Point Theorem, invariance of domain etc. stuff?  If not, what sort of fixed point theorems do you have at your disposal, exactly?

Comment: Maybe you have the "open mapping theorem" for example?

Comment: @JohnSamples Well, I'm able to use any one that works, but I have updated the question, as it comes from a section that only have results on locally invertible $T$ (locally one to one).

Comment: Seems like here is a solution, but uses other methods different from "Local inverse mapping". https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/743713/prove-that-exists-x-0-in-d-such-that-fx-0-0-0?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took me a bit to figure out how to do this without homotopy or winding numbers, which is how it's always proved.  This is an interesting exercise; to see how this normally arises, look up the "dog on a leash" or "walking the dog" lemma of complex analysis.

Define the *boundary* $\partial(A)$ of a set $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ to be the intersection $\overline{A} \cap \overline{\mathbb{R}^n \setminus A}$.  Thus it's the points which are arbitrarily close to both $A$ and its complement; for example, the unit circle is the boundary of $D$.

Note by definition that if $x \in A$ and $x \notin \partial(A)$, then $x$ is in the interior of $A$ - because if every open neighborhood of $x$ intersected the complement of $A$, then $x$ would be in the boundary.  Thus a set is composed of its interior points and its boundary points.

Lemma: If $D \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ and $T$ is $C'$ with non-vanishing Jacobian on (a neighborhood of) $D$ then $T$ doesn't send an interior point of $D$ to the boundary of $T(D)$.

Proof: If $x \in U \subset D$ is a sufficiently small open neighborhood of $x$ in $D$, then $T(U) = V$ is open by the open mapping theorem, and $V = T(U) \subset T(D)$ so that $x$ is an interior point of $T(D)$.  QED

Now returning to your problem, if $B$ is the closed ball centered around $0$ with radius $\frac{1}{3}$ then $T(0) \in B$ since $|T(0) - 0| = |T(0)| \leq \frac{1}{3}$.  However, $T(\mathbb{S}^1) \cap B = \varnothing$ since $|T(p)-p| \leq \frac{1}{3}$ and thus restricting to $\mathbb{S}^1 = \partial(D)$ gives us points at least $\frac{2}{3}$rds away from $0$.  Since $\mathbb{S}^1$ is the boundary of $D$, by the above lemma $T(D)$ has no boundary points in $B$.

Note that $T(D) \cap B$ is non-empty by virtue of containing at least the point $T(0)$.  *Thus* $T(D)$ *must contain all of* $B$ in order to not have any boundary points there: Otherwise, there would be no point contained in both $\overline{T(D)}$ and $\overline{B \setminus T(D)}$.  But then these two sets would be a separation of $B$, which is connected - impossible.

Thus $0 \in B \subset T(D)$, completing the proof.

Comment: Notice that the proof above requires that this bounding distance (here it was $\frac{1}{3}$) be less than $\frac{1}{2}$.  The full-strength Rouche theorem works for any such constant that's less than $1$.

Comment: It seems good, but I'm not very familiar with it, so I trying to read slowly to understand. If you can expand it a little bit, I will appreciate that.

Comment: Ok, I added more details!

Comment: This is an interesting proof, and it's very clear for me now.